# Ravendb TransformResults showing null values for properties populated with Load()

Tags: ravendb

I have two documents Ticket and MenuItem i have created index with TransformResults but problem is i am getting null value for Loaded document in transform

```
public class Ticket
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
    public class MenuItem
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string PriceCategory { get; set; }

    }
```

i have created a index like

```
public class TicketItemGross : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Ticket, TicketItemGross.TicketItemDetails>
    {
        public class TicketItemDetails
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string ItemId { get; set; }
            public string ItemName { get; set; }
            public int Price { get; set; }
            public string PriceCategory { get; set; }
        }
        public TicketItemGross()
        {
            Map = docs => from doc in docs
                          select new
                          {
                              ID = doc.ID,
                              ItemId=doc.ItemId,
                              ItemName=doc.ItemName,
                              Price=doc.Price
                          };
            TransformResults = (database, docs) => from m in docs
                                                   let d = database.Load<MenuItem>(m.ID)
                                                   select new
                                                   {
                                                       ID = m.ID,
                                                       ItemId = m.ItemId,
                                                       ItemName = m.ItemName,
                                                       Price = m.Price,
                                                       PriceCategory=d.PriceCategory
                                                   };
        }
    }
```

and the problem is that when i query data. I get null for PriceCategory but for all other fields i get correct value

here is query

```
IEnumerable<TicketItemGross.TicketItemDetails> list;            
            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                list = session.Query<TicketItemGross.TicketItemDetails, TicketItemGross>();                

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using integer IDs.  When you call `database.Load` in your transform, you'll need to manually convert it to a string ID.

```
database.Load<MenuItem>("MenuItems/" + m.ID)
```

This is one of several places where Raven gets confused if you use integer or guid IDs.  If you use string ids, you won't have this problem.

Also, you might consider using a [results transformer](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/results-transformation/result-transformers) instead.  They are easier than index transformers, which are now obsolete.